# How to feed a site summary to the Google Bot?

Tags: javascript

I noticed that for my site summary the Google Bot seemed to be putting up the first batch of text it found.  This happened to be the noscript tag that told the user to turn JavaScript on , if it was not enabled.

I thought I would thwart it, by putting a hidden div before that, that actually contained a site summary.

Now, I find in its latest parsing that it actually loaded the page, and ran the JavaScript, bypassed the hidden divs and used the dynamic content which was generated.

Oddly, my app identified the bot as the Safari Browser, but it did not detect a version.

To make a long story short, how do I get my site summary into the Google listing correctly?

It is a one page application that requires JavaScript and only supports FireFox and Safari currently.

Here is what it ignored

**Snippet 1 (in head)**

```
<meta name='description' content='My Summary'>
```

**Snippet 2 (in body)**

```
<body>
  <div id='google_bot' style='display:none'>
    My Summary
  </div>
```

**Update:**

Last time it crawled my page, it was detected as Chrome 22, and in the site summary it did in fact use the meta-tag with name description.

Comment: Do you have a description meta tag?

Comment: It's just ten football fields of servers, it not an actual robot you can catch and hold in your hand ?

Comment: Google decides whether or not the description accurately reflects the page content.  There may be some undocumented hacks, but the correct method is to update the description to something it believes (use words on the page).  It has a lot of problems though.  YouTube often has "You need adobe flash...".  I've filed a bug report about it in the past.

Comment: It's a spam prevention technique.  If a page has a description of "Cute Kitten Images for FREE", and is selling Viagra, they don't want to honor the description tag.

Comment: @Smurfette I highly doubt that the world's biggest search engine company cannot write a parser that recognises HTML with single quotes around the attributes.

Comment: Arguably, this falls foul of the guideline that ["If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). In an ideal world, there would be a simple answer to this, because all web developers would be honestly trying to fairly represent their sites. In practice, there is an entire "Search Engine Optimisation" industry dedicated to the morally grey business of getting your site (and perhaps business) represented better on Google et al.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be pretty easy to find out.

Put a site description in 3 places, the meta tag, the hidden div, and also what Google bot found in its last search.  Use something small to differentiate the 3, like punctuation.

Next.  Submit your page to be crawled by Google using Google Web Tools so you don't have to wait.  It should only Take about 15 minutes.

Once it has been fetched, you can verify that it pulled up what you wanted it to, and from there you can submit it to the index.

From there see what changed, and verify what it crawled.

Strange that it identified itself as Safari.

Here is some information on what the user agent should look like:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en

Comment: Regarding the user agent, note that several on the page you link to are deliberately similar to browsers. Also, that list is for targeting directives *to* the bots, not detecting their traffic; they may also crawl with spoofed user agents to detect sites attempting to trick the indexer.

Comment: The user agents for the Google Bots are clearly shown on the link I posted.  This question/answer is for Google only per the OP.  Papa is boss.

Answer (score 3):

If you have real unique new continuous interesting content, then you may generate [a well marked-up RSS feed](http://feed2.w3.org/docs/rss2.html), `RSS -> Rich Site Summary` with only the relevant things and add a meta tag like

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="${linkToFeed}">
```

I think Google Bot loves it as soon as it verifies that the RSS-Feed represents the content of the actual page

Comment: interesting, what led you to this hypothesis?

Comment: because the whole front-end is unneccessary for collecting main-data, it´s important for collecting data about how user experience the data but if you offer an easy parseable machine-readable-format why not take it and save some trees, imagine how much crap and workarrounds and tons of code a webdesigner puts arround the interesting data. No guarantee for anything i think its just logic

Comment: @johnSmith Google are not in the business of "saving trees" (even imaginary digital ones) they are in the business of serving relevant and *spam free* search results. Unfortunately, this means they *cannot* trust a machine-readable version of the page, because you could be lying to the machine about what you are showing to the humans.